# copyWithZone error -[DataObject setECGCount:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ipad, crash, copy

My application crashed with the following error:

> -[Data Object set ECGCount:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x281671ad0

I am trying to pass data between my main viewController class into DataObject class which will then finally pass this information into IntervalGraph class.

I am doing this using copyWithZone however am getting stuck.

here is the **viewContoller.h** Class:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "CorePlot-CocoaTouch.h"

@interface ViewController : UIViewController<CPTPlotDataSource>

@property (nonatomic, assign) int eCGCount;
@property (nonatomic, assign) int eCGheartRate;

@end
```

and the relevant code in **viewController.m**

```
@property (nonatomic) DataObject *maxRecordedHR, *minRecordedHR, *currentData, *continuousData, *seizureData;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
  [super viewDidLoad];

       [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter addObserver:self
                                                                                                
                                             selector:@selector(sensorDataUpdated)
                                                                                                  
                                              name:@"LYRDeviceCommunicatorDataUpdated"
                                                                                                    
                                            object:nil];   

       self.rollingAverageHRArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithCapacity:180];
       self.currentData           = [[DataObject alloc]init];
       self.continuousData        = [[DataObject alloc]init];
       self.seizureData           = [[DataObject alloc]init];
}

//fired by a 1 second timer
-(void)startIntervalGraph {
  [self sensorDataUpdated];
  if (self.currentData.heartrate == 0 )
  {NSLog(@"No data");
          
  } else {
  
  self.rollingAverageLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"rolling 3 min average %1.1f", self.currentData.rollingaverageheartrate];
  [self.intervalGraph addDataObject:self.currentData]; // something wrong here
  [self.intervalGraph updateGraph];
          NSLog(@"Updating Interval Graph");
          
  }
}
 
 -(void) sensorDataUpdated {
     //Heart Rate
     self.currentData.heartrate = self.eCGheartRate;
     NSLog(@"Current Data %d", self.currentData.heartrate);
  
}

-(void)setECGCount:(int)eCGCount
{
      self.eCGheartRate = (int) eCGCount;
      eCGCount = self.eCGCount;
      NSLog(@"eCGCount %d", self.eCGCount);
}
```

then the **DataObject.h** class

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface DataObject : NSObject <NSCopying>

@property int heartrate;
@property float rollingaverageheartrate;
@property float rrinterval;
@property NSTimeInterval occurrence;
@property NSInteger minHRsetting;
@property NSInteger maxHRsetting;
@property int alarmtripped;

@end
```

and the **DataObject.m**

```
#import "DataObject.h"
#import "CRPC_300SDK.h"
#import "ViewController.h"

@implementation DataObject

- (id)copyWithZone:(NSZone *)zone
{
      id copy =  class alloc] init];
  
      if (copy) {
              // Set primitives
              [copy setECGCount:self.heartrate]; //THIS IS WHERE THE CRASH OCCURS.
              //[copy setRrinterval:self.rrinterval];
              [copy setRollingaverageheartrate:self.rollingaverageheartrate];
              [copy setOccurrence:self.occurrence];
              [copy setMinHRsetting:self.minHRsetting];
              [copy setMaxHRsetting:self.maxHRsetting];
              [copy setAlarmtripped:self.alarmtripped];
          
      }
  
      return copy;
  
}
```

When i call

```
[copy setECGCOUNT:self.heartrate];
```

The app crashes with the following error:

> 2020-08-20 11:58:57.884543+0100 PulseGuardian[3927:2317144]
> -[DataObject setECGCount:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x281671ad0
>
> 2020-08-20 11:58:57.885908+0100 PulseGuardian[3927:2317144] *
> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
> 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[DataObject setECGCount:]:
> unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x281671ad0'

How can i fix this problem?

Comment: `[copy setECGCount:self.heartrate];` => `[copy setHeartrate:self.heartrate];` What's `setECGCount` method?

Comment: `DataObject` doesn't have a property called `ECGCount` so it's not possible to set it.

Comment: @Larme thank you, i was being an idiot and this solved the issue. App is now working without issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Larme pointed out in the comments, i was referencing the wrong method in the

**DataObject.m**

The code read:

```
[copy setECGCount:self.heartrate];
```

when it should have read:

```
[copy setHeartrate:self.heartrate];
```

once code was changed the app worked as it should. Silly error on my behalf but will leave this here in case it helps anybody else in the future.